Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection (.Rmd)
I am using vcftools in an .Rmd file to plot my basic vcf stats. I had this code working for a while, but yesterday it decided to stop and give me an error.
Thanks in advance!
The code I ran and the error that I received is below.
prefix <- "./wss_all_data/all.snps"
plot.vcf.stats(prefix

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
4.file(file, "rt")
3.read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,
dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
2.read.delim(paste(prfx, ".imiss", sep = ""), sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
1.plot.vcf.stats(prefix)

I saw another question about this, but I tried that answer and it did not solve my problem.
Interestingly, when I run it from another .Rmd file (with all the same commands), it works just fine. I have the .Rmd file in the directory with all of the data.
Based on some trouble shooting, I also tried
{r, fig.width=8, fig.height=6}
wss_all_data <- "wss_all_data"
imiss_file <- file.path('wss_all_data/all.snps.imiss')
ldepth_mean_file <- file.path(wss_all_data, "all.snps.ldepth.mean")
idepth_file <- file.path(wss_all_data, "all.snps.idepth")
lmiss_file <- file.path(wss_all_data, "all.snps.lmiss")`

Now plot.
{r}
  #Function to read and plot .imiss file
  plot_imiss <- function(file) {
  data <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  ggplot(data, aes(x = F_MISS)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, fill = "blue", color = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Missing Data Proportion",
     x = "F_MISS",
     y = "Count")
  }

#Function to read and plot .ldepth.mean file
 plot_ldepth_mean <- function(file) {
 data <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 ggplot(data, aes(x = MEAN_DEPTH)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, fill = "green", color = "black") +
theme_minimal() +
labs(title = "Site Mean Depth",
     x = "MEAN_DEPTH",
     y = "Count")
 }

 #Function to read and plot .idepth file
plot_idepth <- function(file) {
data <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggplot(data, aes(x = MEAN_DEPTH)) +
 geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, fill = "orange", color = "black") +
theme_minimal() +
labs(title = "Individual Mean Depth",
     x = "MEAN_DEPTH",
     y = "Count")
}

#Function to read and plot .lmiss file
plot_lmiss <- function(file) {
data <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggplot(data, aes(x = F_MISS)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, fill = "purple", color = "black") +
theme_minimal() +
labs(title = "Site Missingness",
     x = "F_MISS",
     y = "Count")
}

#Generate and display the plots
print(plot_imiss(imiss_file))
print(plot_ldepth_mean(ldepth_mean_file))
print(plot_idepth(idepth_file))
print(plot_lmiss(lmiss_file))`

And received this error: Warning: cannot open file 'wss_all_data/all.snps.imiss': No such file or directory Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

can you run the list.files() function for the subfolder where you want to save it to? or if there have been any changes to your project directory structure.
